# Como agregar subtitulos a un reproductor de videos

Tags: javascript, html5, video

estoy intentando hacer un reproductor de videos, pero no se como añadir los subtitulos en vtt y se switchen correctamente con su video correspondiente.
No se como agregarlo al javascript ni al html5.
Esto es lo que llevo para cambiar entre videos.

```
function init() {
    document._video = document.getElementById("video");
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

//switching videos (playlist)
var videos =
[
 [
    "recursos/zelda-caption.jpg",
    "recursos/zelda.mp4"
 ],
 [
    "recursos/mario-caption.jpg",
    "recursos/mario.mp4"
 ],
 [
    "recursos/smash-caption.jpg",
    "recursos/smash.mp4"
 ]
 ];
function switchVideo(n) {
    if (n >= videos.length) n = 0;

    var mp4 = document.getElementById("mp4");
    var parent = mp4.parentNode;

    document._video.setAttribute("poster", videos[n][0]);
    mp4.setAttribute("src", videos[n][1]);
  document._video.load();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En HTML5, puedes agregar subtítulos a un reproductor de videos utilizando el elemento `<track>`. Este elemento se utiliza para especificar una pista de subtítulos, y se coloca dentro del elemento `<video>`.

```
<video>
  <track kind="subtitles" src="subtitulos.vtt" />
</video>
```

También puedes usar el atributo label para especificar un nombre para la pista de subtítulos, que se mostrará al usuario cuando elija qué pista de subtítulos utilizar.

```
<video>
  <track kind="subtitles" src="subtitulos.vtt" label="Español" />
</video>
```

De esta manera, los subtítulos se mostrarán en el reproductor de videos con el nombre "Español".

Además, puedes usar el atributo default del elemento  para especificar si los subtítulos se deben mostrar por defecto o no.

```
<video>
  <track kind="subtitles" src="subtitulos.vtt" label="Español" default="true" />
</video>
```

En [este articulo en gringo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video) adicionalmente hallaras una explicación de algunas modificaciones de estilo que podrías usar.